# TypeError:n.default.configureProps is not a function.In’n.default.configureProps(Object.keys(p),Object.keys(b))’,n.default.configureProps is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

[image]

TypeError: n.default.configureProps is not a function. (In ’n.default.configureProps(Object.keys(p),Object.keys(b))’,’n.default.configureProps’ is undefined) is coming after updating 'react-native-reanimated' package in react native application.